# Can the p-adic logarithm be considered as a ring homomorphism?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

**P-adic numbers $ \ \mathbb{Q}_p \ $ and Non-Archimedian analysis:**

We know **real logarithm** from $ \ (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} \ $ is a **group homomorphism**  in Archimedian field.

Similarly , we know that the **p-adic logarithm** expressed by $ \ \log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n} \ $  is also **group homomorphism** in p-adic field or **Non-Archimedian field** .

In P-adic field there are both addition and muliplication structure .

My question is-

**Can the p-adic logarithm be considered as a ring homomorphism?**

Help me with at least a hints also.

Comment: As @Watson makes clear, for something to be a ring homomorphism, it must be defined on a ring. That does not seem to be the case for the $p$-adic logarithm.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept it. Would explain what will be the image of $ \ \mathbb{Z}_p \ $ under the p-adic homomorphism ? It is required to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @yourmath : again, the $p$-adic logarithm is only defined on $1 + p \Bbb Z_p$ : the power series you wrote doesn't converge on the whole of $\Bbb Z_p$. So it has no meaning to ask what is the image of $\Bbb Z_p$. But the image of $1+p\Bbb Z_p$ of $\log_p$ is $p\Bbb Z_p$, when $p>2$ — see Katok, _$p$-adic analysis compared with real_, prop. 3.29, p. 93.

Comment: it is ok. For the time being, I have no question. Thank you so much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that the $p$-adic logarithm is defined only on $1+p \Bbb Z_p$. Indeed, the sequence $a_n := (-1)^{n+1}/n$ satisfies 
$$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|_p} = p^{v_p(n) / n} \longrightarrow 1,  
\qquad
\text{when}\;\; n \to \infty,$$
so that the series defining $\log(1+x)$ is converging on $p \Bbb Z_p$.

Secondly, the subset $1+p \Bbb Z_p \subset \Bbb Z_p^{\times}$ is actually a multiplicative subgroup. 
Then it is true that
$$\log_p : 1+p \Bbb Z_p \to (\Bbb Q_p,+)$$
is a group homomorphism, i.e. $\log_p(xy) = \log_p(x) + \log_p(y)$. It has no sense to ask whether this is a ring morphism, since $1+p \Bbb Z_p$ has no zero element (so it is not a subring of $\Bbb Z_p$).

Comment: The claim about "group homomorphism" is [theorem 8.5 here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf). This holds also when $p=2$.

Comment: According to proposition IV.2, p. 87 in Koblitz's _p-adic Numbers_, there is a unique group morphism $\Bbb C_p^{\times} \to \Bbb C_p$ extending $\log_p$ and which sends $p$ to $0$ (but this morphism is not directly defined as a power series).

Comment: Well, @Watson, the extended log that K mentions uses the series definition for numbers $z$ with $|z-1|<1$, then builds outward from there.